# Probability and time

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

I've heard somewhere from someone about a theorem that roughly says "the probability of an event decreases as time increases"

I couldn't find the exact theorem (assign it exists at all.)

So figure I should ask all of you great mathematicans here if anyone has ever heard of this.

Comment: There is the [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), for which this is a natural part of the PDF.

Comment: Almost sounded like the [Monte Carlo Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy) with a twist (as in the probability that I will continue to repeatedly lose decreases as time increases).

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of one of two things:

1) The [Poisson Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), a probability-distribution that examines the changing probability of an event over a certain time interval.

2) A cultural proverb that posits that "the probability of an event decreases as time goes on." The idea here is that if an event hasn't happened for a long time, then the probability of it occurring must actually be quite low, because it is more likely that the occurrence of the event is unlikely, than for a likely event not to have occurred during this period of time. For example: "We haven't had a flood in a hundred years, so we probably won't have a flood this year, either." You feel much more comfortable making this claim than "we didn't have a flood last year, so we probably won't have a flood this year either."

This is a non-rigorous adaptation of [frequentist inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_inference). It's not a theorem, and it's pretty much not true, either. It's just a saying with a little bit of truth to it - but it's certainly not to be relied on.

EDIT: If we're being really rigorous, the saying misrepresents probability inference. It is related to something called the [Gambler's Fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).